# Terraform : How to autoscale managed instance group in GCP with stackdriver metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to autoscale instance group based on pubsub metric `pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages` . For every 2 
 undelivered  messages, i want to spin up a new worker instance. Manually, This is quite easy with [GUI config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClY3.png).

Now, I wrote terraform code for automating this so that we can repeat it.
I looked through [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_autoscaler.html) for autoscaler and couldn't find a way to do that even though they have mentioned using `customMetricUtilizations` . I just couldn't make it work.

Here is my autoscaler part :

```
resource "google_compute_autoscaler" "foobar" {
  name   = "scaler"
  zone   = "${var.region}-a"
  target = "${google_compute_instance_group_manager.appserver.self_link}"



 autoscaling_policy = {
    max_replicas    = 10
    min_replicas    = 0
    cooldown_period = 60

    metric  {
      name = "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages"
      target = "2"
      type = "GAUGE"
    }
  }
}
```

Could anybody please help me figure it out.

Comment: I think you have wrong configured at least in my point of view the name filed should be the target value that's mean the type of the API. and the target should be "2" since you want to spin an instance for every 2 undelivered message. I found this document on Google Cloud [using instance assignment to scale based on a pub/sub queue](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#example_using_instance_assignment_to_scale_based_on_a_pubsub_queue)

Comment: Here you will find the Google [autoscaler API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/autoscalers/insert)

Answer (score 0):

I think the custom metrics like for pubsub and others work with zonal autoscaler and for your use case you need to use the regional autoscaler as mentioned below

For regional autoscaler(for your use-case) -

```
resource "google_compute_region_autoscaler" "foobar" {
  name   = "my-region-autoscaler"
  region = "us-central1"
  target = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.foobar.id

  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = 5
    min_replicas    = 1
    cooldown_period = 60

    metric  {
     name = "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages"
     target = "2"
     type = "GAUGE"
    }
  }
}
```

For zonal instance group manager with custom metrics

```
resource "google_compute_autoscaler" "default" {
  provider = google-beta

  name   = "my-autoscaler"
  zone   = "us-central1-f"
  target = google_compute_instance_group_manager.default.id

  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = 5
    min_replicas    = 1
    cooldown_period = 60

    metric {
      name                       = "pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages"
      filter                     = "resource.type = pubsub_subscription AND resource.label.subscription_id = our-subscription"
      single_instance_assignment = 65535
    }
  }
}
```

[google_compute_region_autoscaler terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_region_autoscaler)

[google_compute_autoscaler](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_autoscaler)